Python pynput doesn't work correct when Windows choosen language doesn't contain appropriate char
i am trying to simulate keyboard input using pynput.keyboard Controller
for example, here is a function that is supposed to minimize all windows
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as KeyboardController
keyboard = KeyboardController()
    def minimize_all_windows__win_m():
        keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
        keyboard.press("m")
        keyboard.release("m")
        keyboard.release(Key.cmd)

And it works perfectly until i switch my keyboard layout (from english to any that doesn't contain "m" char, like cyrilic languages (ua)). in that case it will just type "m"
the reverse case is the same:
# will minimize all windows if cyrilic language chosen, but type "ь" in other case 
def minimize_all_windows__win_m():     
    keyboard.press(Key.cmd)     
    keyboard.press("ь")     
    keyboard.release("ь")     
    keyboard.release(Key.cmd)

I tried modifying this code by changing the keyboard layout using py_win_keyboard_layout
however it does switch the language, it still doesn't work correctly (still only typind char)
import py_win_keyboard_layout
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as KeyboardController, Key
eng_code = 67699721
keyboard = KeyboardController()

def get_keyboard_layout_name():
    return py_win_keyboard_layout.get_foreground_window_keyboard_layout()

def set_keyboard_layout_name(layout_name):  py_win_keyboard_layout.change_foreground_window_keyboard_layout(layout_name)

def minimize_all_windows__win_m():
    current_layout = get_keyboard_layout_name()
    set_keyboard_layout_name(eng_code)
    keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
    keyboard.press("m")
    keyboard.release("m")
    keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
    set_keyboard_layout_name(current_layout)

I also tried pyautogui, pydirectinput and keyboard modules but didn't succses with any of them
but i find pynput.keyboard still most usable because for example
pydirectinput didn't even manage to press "D" (pydirectinput.press("D") didn't work for me), while pynput did
So my purpose is to simulate keyboard input in such way that it doesn't matter what language is currently chosen, the caps lock, num lock and other appropriate keys state, also working with any language characters

pydirectinput appears to use windows key codes, so you probably have to track state of keystroke with respect to modifier keys. pynput.keyboard doesn't appear to use scan codes, virtual keys or keycodes, but relies on the character generated.

You should try pyautogui.
